# Correct approach to making down migration for making column nullable type

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I have a migration defined like so:

```
Schema::table('campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('rates')->nullable(true)->change();
});
```

So I'm making "rates" nullable.

How should I handle the reverse migration? If there's no data in that column do I just set a default? I can't make it not null because that would violate integrity constraint. Can I not do anything about it?

Comment: My approach is to not write reverse migrations in such cases. I only write reverse migrations where it makes sense (dropping tables and dropping/adding columns that would break previous migrations). The problem in your case is that adding default value doesn't really reverse the migration, it just changes the structure 1 more time.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. Just wondering if anyone had any better ideas. Thanks for your input.